# How to use Continuously (-c) with grep on netstat?

Tags: linux, grep, netstat

How can I use netstat -c option with grep without repeating the info?

Example:

```
sudo netstat -tapc (works fine)
```

I want to do the same but only for the http lines:

```
sudo netstat -tapc | grep http
```

The code above generates duplicated lines.

How to track the -tapc info only for the http lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you need to forget `netstat -c` and use `watch` instead:

```
watch 'netstat -tap|grep http'
```

You may want to add options to `watch`, including `-n` to set the repetition rate, and `-d` to highlight differences.